# Play mpeg-2 file with 608/708 embedded captions out Decklink SDI

Tags: ffmpeg, caption, decklink, blackmagic-design

I have built ffmpeg with decklink support, it plays my mpg file fine out the SDI but not seeing any captions on my works broadcast monitor (JVC DT-V17G1Z).  This monitor shows captions on SDI from my Mojito card but trying to get it to work with a BlackMagic 4k extreme.  The mpg file has embedded 608 and 708 captions.  Using the to play-

```
ffmpeg -i C:\video\RD2838_720p.mpg -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 "DeckLink 4K Extreme"
```

MediaInfo on captinos:

```
Text #1
```

ID                                       : 4096 (0x1000)-CC1
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : EIA-608
Muxing mode                              : A/53 / DTVCC Transport
Muxing mode, more info                   : Muxed in Video #1
Duration                                 : 28 min 30 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Stream size                              : 0.00 Byte (0%)
Language                                 : English
CaptionServiceName                       : CC1

Text #2
ID                                       : 4096 (0x1000)-1
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : EIA-708
Muxing mode                              : A/53 / DTVCC Transport
Muxing mode, more info                   : Muxed in Video #1
Duration                                 : 28 min 30 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Stream size                              : 0.00 Byte (0%)
Language                                 : English

How do I get the Decklink 4k to pass the captions?  Thanks!

Comment: Did this but still not working..       ffmpeg -i C:\video\RD2838_720p.mpg -f decklink -teletext_lines all -vcodec v210 "DeckLink 4K Extreme"

Comment: Was mistaken, needing EIA-708 and EIA-608 (north America) and not DVB/Teletext stream (euro)...  I believe I need lavfi, subcc and/ or -a53cc..  Was able to extract captions from my file to SRT with this but looking to just pass them out SDI..  ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "movie=RD2838_720p.ts[out0+subcc]" -map s output.srt